# How to catch xth pattern1 to pattern2

Tags: bash, for-loop, parsing, sed, grep

this is my example to explain my question :

```
Bug Day 2022-01-13:
Security-Fail 248975
Resolve:
...
Bug Day 2022-01-25:
Security-Fail 225489
Security-Fail 225256
Security-Fail 225236
Resolve:
...
Bug Day 2022-02-02:
Security-Fail 222599
Resolve:
```

So, I have a big file that contain multiple security vulnerabilities.
I want to obtain that :

```
2022-01-13;248975
2022-01-25;225489,225256,225236
2022-02-02;222599
```

I though about doing something like

```
bugDayNb=$(grep "Bug Day" | wc -l)

for i in $bugDayNb; do
    echo "myBugsFile" | grep -A10 -m$i "Bug Day"
done
```

The problem of this command is, if there are more than 10 Security-Fail, it won't works, and if I put a "-A50" it may take the next Security-Fail of the next Bug Day.

So I would prefer a way to **sed** or something like that from xth "Bug Day" to xth "Resolve"

Thank you !!

Comment: Does your input actually have `...` to separate the various bug blocks? I'm also not clear on what output you are expecting. Does `awk -v n=2 '/^Bug Day/{c++} c==n; /^Resolve:/ && c==n{exit}'` give what you want?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear.

I want to obtain something like that
"2022-01-13;248975"
"2022-01-25;225489,225256,225236"
"2022-02-02;222599"

and the "..." is representative, it's a bunch of text.

In the real security file, each Bug Day are separated with ----------------------

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```sh
$ awk '/^Bug Day/{d=$NF; s=""}
       /^Security-Fail/{d = d s $NF; s=","}
       /^Resolve:/{print d}' ip.txt
2022-01-13:248975
2022-01-25:225489,225256,225236
2022-02-02:222599
```

- `/^Bug Day/{d=$NF; s=""}` save the date to variable `d` if line starts with `Bug Day` and initialize `s` to empty string

  - use `{d=$NF; sub(/:$/, ";", d); s=""}` if you want `;` instead of `:`
- `/^Security-Fail/{d = d s $NF; s=","}` when line starts with `Security-Fail` append the number to `d` variable and set `s` so that further appends will be separated by `,`
- `/^Resolve:/{print d}` print the results when `Resolve:` is seen

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
/Bug Day/{
  sub(/:$/,"",$NF)
  bugVal=$NF
  next
}
/^Security-Fail/{
  secVal=(secVal?secVal ",":"")$NF
  next
}
/^Resolve:/ && bugVal && secVal{
  print bugVal";"secVal
  bugVal=secVal=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
/Bug Day/{                          ##Checking condition if line contains Bug day then do following.
  sub(/:$/,"",$NF)                  ##Substituting : at last of $NF in current line.
  bugVal=$NF                        ##Creating bugVal which has $NF value in it.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^Security-Fail/{                   ##Checking if line starts from Security-Fail then do following.
  secVal=(secVal?secVal ",":"")$NF  ##Creating secVal which has $NF value in it and keep adding value to it with delimiter of comma here.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^Resolve:/ && bugVal && secVal{    ##Checking condition if line starts from Resolve: and bugVal is SET and secVal is SET then do following.
  print bugVal";"secVal             ##printing bugVal semi-colon secVal here.
  bugVal=secVal=""                  ##Nullifying bugVal and secVal here.
}
'  Input_file                       ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/Bug Day/{:a;N;/Resolve/!ba;s/.* //mg;y/\n/,/;s/:,(.*),.*/;\1/p}' file
```

Gather up lines between `Bug Day` and `Resolve` and format accordingly.

If you want to be selective about a single day or range of days, use:

```
sed -nE '/Bug Day/{x;s/^/x/;/^x{1,3}$/!{x;d};x
         :a;N;/Resolve/!ba;s/.* //mg;y/\n/,/;s/:,/;/;s/(.*),.*/\1/p}' file
```

The above command displays the first 3 days i.e. 1 to 3

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try an `awk` solution:

```
awk '/^Bug Day/ {f=1; line=$0; next}                    # start of block
    f {line=line ORS $0}                                # append the line if "f" is set
    /^Security-Fail/ {g=1}                              # the block contains "Security-Fail"
    /^Resolve/ {if (g) print line; f=g=0; line=""}      # end of block
' input_file
```

If you prefer a one-liner:

```
awk '/^Bug Day/{f=1; line=$0; next} f{line=line ORS $0} /^Security-Fail/{g=1} /^Resolve/{if (g) print line; f=g=0; line=""}' input_file
```